# Convert a docker run statement into a docker-compose.yml file

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have the following image that works great via the command

```
docker run my-hello-world echo hello!
```

Obviously a contrived example however how can I convert this into a small docker-compose.yml file? docker-compose doesn't appear to have a run command. Can it not run containers???

Comment: You can specify run command using [`command`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#command) in your Compose file.

Comment: Docker run is  used for single container, while docker-compose.yml file is used for running a group of containers together. And yes, docker-compose.yml CAN run containers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can run container's command with Docker Compose and provision containers. But you don't use `docker run` instead you use `docker-compose up` and `down` to up and down containers. In this case, try create a `docker-compose.yml` file with the contents:

```
version: '2'

services:
 app1:
  image: my-hello-world
  command: "echo hello!"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just paste your run command to this website and let it do the work for you!

https://composerize.com/